# Pageinit and Ready Events Irregularities

Tags: javascript, jquery, listview, jquery-mobile, cordova

Here is a link to the fiddle of the issue I am facing [with pageinit and ready events](http://jsfiddle.net/XNvWy/)

With the fiddle link everything works using onLoad and onDOMready. "Everything" meaning

1. The subject listings is properly loaded with a popup on click that lists the modules
2. The Module list gives an alert on click

But in my code trying to bind the events to the respective ids after pageinit is not working

```
$('#home').on('pageinit', function() {
 $('#modules').on('vclick','li', function(e){
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
       var module = $(this).attr("category");
       moduleClick(module);       
       });
});
```

Listening for $(document).ready( function() {)} does not  popup the Modules.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(window).load(function() {
    ...
});
```

or

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, true);
function onDeviceReady(){
    ...
}
```

Comment: $(window).load does not popup the Modules and the  eventlistener does not does not bind the event.

Comment: Try huck like this (simple add code bofore your):
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, true);
    function onDeviceReady(){
        $('#home').trigger('pageinit');
    }

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open a popup as soon as your page loads, its better you do it in pagecreate, as of JQM 1.4 pageinit is deprecated, but just a popup open will not work due to some chaining issue, you need to add some timeout as well

Put an anchor with href to the popup and fire click

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", function(event) {
    setTimeout(function(){
       $("a#popupOpen").click();
    },200);

});
```

or

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", function(event) {
    setTimeout(function(){
       $( "#popup" ).panel( "open" );
    },200);

});
```